# MVC in ASP.NET - Designing a database and views with drop-down list

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor, drop-down-menu, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm a newbie in MVC and i have some issues with my project. What i'm trying to do is a user-editable platform for renting cars. 
In my project I would like to have options like:

- Adding a car to the database
- Adding a new car rent request with dropdown list of all cars in the database
- Register/Login
- Viewing history of rent requests for each of cars in the database

Project will be based on *.sdf database with Entity Framework.
I've made a class file in Models/ directory :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data.Entity;
namespace MVC4.Models
{
   public class Car
   {
     public int ID {get; set;}
     public string Make {get; set;}
     public string Model {get; set;}
     public virtual ICollection<Car> Cars{ get; set; }
   }

   public class Request
   {
     public int ID {get; set;}
     public string User {get; set;}
     public int CarID{ get; set; }
     public virtual Car Car { get; set; }
   }

   public class CarDBContext : DbContext
   {
     public DbSet<Car> Cars { get; set; }
     public DbSet<Request> Requests { get; set; }
   }
}
```

Controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using MVC4.Models;

namespace MVC4.Controllers
{ 
public class RequestController : Controller
{
    private CarDBContext db = new Car1DBContext();

    //
    // GET: /Request/

    public ViewResult Index()
    {
        return View(db.Requests.ToList());
    }

    //
    // GET: /Request/Details/5

    public ViewResult Details(int id)
    {
        Wypozyczenie1 Request = db.Requests.Find(id);
        return View(request);
    }

    //
    // GET: /Request/Create

    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    } 

    //
    // POST: /Request/Create

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Request request)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Requests.Add(request);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");  
        }

        return View(request);
    }

    //
    // GET: /Request/Edit/5

    public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        Request request= db.Requests.Find(id);
        return View(request);
    }

    //
    // POST: /Request/Edit/5

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(Request requests)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(request).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(request);
    }

    //
    // GET: /Request/Delete/5

    public ActionResult Delete(int id)
    {
        Request request= db.Requests.Find(id);
        return View(request);
    }

    //
    // POST: /Request/Delete/5

    [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
    public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
    {            
        Request request = db.Requests.Find(id);
        db.Requests.Remove(request);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        db.Dispose();
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
}
```

Create request view:

```
........

 <div class="editor-field">
    ViewBag.PossibleCategories = context.Cars;
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ID,
    ((IEnumerable<MVC4.Models.Car>)ViewBag.PossibleCategories)
    .Select(option => new SelectListItem {
    Text = (option == null ? "None" : option.Make), 
    Value = option.ID.ToString(),
    Selected = (Model != null) && (option.ID == Model.CarID)
}), "Choose...")
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CarID)

</div>
..........
```

This is not working for me. 
How to populate this dropdown and make this View able to insert data into the database?
Thanks for your help. I've spent many hours on this and can't figure it out. Sorry for my english, I hope you guys understand me.

i get error:

```
Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: source.


Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the 
current web request. Please review the stack trace for more 
information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: source

Source Error: 


Line 32:         <div class="editor-field">
Line 33:         ViewBag.PossibleCategories = context.Cars;
Line 34:     @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ID,
Line 35:         ((IEnumerable<MVC6.Models.Car>)ViewBag.PossibleCategories)
Line 36:         .Select(option => new SelectListItem {
```

This is my Request/ View:

```
@model IEnumerable<MVC6.Models.Request>

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
@Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table>
<tr>
    <th>
        User
    </th>
    <th>
        Car
    </th>
    <th></th>
</tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.User)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Car.Make)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.ID }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.ID }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.ID })
    </td>
</tr>
}

</table>
```

Comment: *Not working* is a pretty poor problem description. I hope you will improve your question explaining what does this mean. What is the expected and the actual result?

Comment: I've added desctiption of an error which i get. Thanks for help.

Comment: When do you get the error? When the view is rendered (GET) or when you click the submit button (POST)?

Comment: i get this error while accesing localhost:port/Request/Create

Answer (score 0):

I found it a bit of a tough slog to get the dropdownlist going too, but I figured it out finally...

As usual there are a few ways to do it.  Here's how I did it:

In the controller I created the selectlist and put in the ViewBag

`ViewBag.mylist = new SelectList(db.Whatever, "ValueColumn", "DisplayColumn");`

Then in my View:

```
Html.DropDownList("myname", (SelectList)ViewBag.mylist, "Select Something",

   new
   {
       @onchange = "form.submit();"
   })
```

If you put a form on your view then this will also post the form (if you need that).  I think you can also do this kind of thing in a ViewModel.  This seemed the easiest way for me, although a bit clunky it seems.  Happy to hear feedback.

Answer (score 0):

You can learn a little bit from [Creating Car Rental Application in ASP.NET MVC3 Razor](http://blog.scheduler-net.com/post/2012/06/15/creating-car-rental-application-in-asp-net-mvc3-razor.aspx).